# Can someone help me portforward?

Tags: ip, port-forwarding, ipv4

Like others, I seek to port forward a Minecraft server. I do not know what I am doing wrong, every time I try to set up an IPv4 portforward, it never works out. Whenever I input:

[image: https://gyazo.com/ca36f41042f325165bee31bc66ddf0d0]

I get:

[image: https://gyazo.com/1663cff4257fff022f290654cfd9380f]

For reference it is a Ubee DDW 365.

Comment: It's a Ubee DDW 365, and the first screenshot show that it is the only rule.

Comment: Ok.

Gateway - 192.168.0.1
IPv4 - 192.168.0.1
Computer IPv4 - 173.92.194.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local IP you entered is most likely wrong, as 192.168.0.1 is probably the internal IP of the router. You should enter the one of the Minecraft server.

Comment: Should I change 192.168.0.1 to 173.92.194.16 in that case?

Comment: You are probably checking your "computer IP" at the wrong place. `173.92.194.16` should be your public IP. You need something like `192.168.0.2`. Look for it by checking network options/settings in the system.

Comment: After checking, I believe it is 192.168.0.10, but that does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got it! I just kept clicking the "remove all" button because I was bored, decided to try again and it worked!